# Puppeteer.Connect browserWSEndpoint with headless true?

Tags: javascript, automation, puppeteer, screen-scraping, headless

The script below needs to connect to an already open instance of Google Chrome because I am already logged in there with my username and password. If it opens a new one, it will need to log in again, and the environment requires two-factor authentication. Therefore, the ideal solution is to use the one that is already open. So far so good.

The only thing I need now is to ensure that it does not maximize every time the script runs, since it is a script that will run in a loop until I stop it manually or if it encounters an error.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const requests = '<my_url>'

let browser; 

async function startbrowser() { 
    if (!browser) {
        browser = await puppeteer.connect({
            browserWSEndpoint: 'ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/<my_address>', 
        });
    }
    return browser;
}

async function monitor() {
    try {
        await startbrowser();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(requests, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

        const frame = await page.frames().find(f => f.name() === '<frame_name>');
        if (!frame) {
            console.log('Frame not found');
            return;
        }
    
        const noRecords = await frame.evaluate(() => document.body.innerText.includes("No records"));
        if (noRecords) {
            console.log("No records to display found, script will run again after 3 minutes");
            await page.close(); 
            setTimeout(() => monitor().catch(console.error), 180000); //3min

        } else {
            console.log("Records found, proceeding with actions.");
            const coordinates = await frame.evaluate(() => {
                const el = document.body;
                const {x, y} = el.getBoundingClientRect();
                return {x, y};
            });

            await page.mouse.click(coordinates.x + 80, coordinates.y + 240, { button: 'right' });
            await page.mouse.move(coordinates.x + 120, coordinates.y + 300);
            await page.mouse.click(coordinates.x + 120, coordinates.y + 300, { button: 'left' });
            await page.close();
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("An error occurred:", error);
    } finally {
        setTimeout(() => monitor().catch(console.error), 10000); //10s
        console.log("waiting 3 minutes to run again");
    }
}
monitor().catch(console.error);
```

I tried running the code above, but every time it runs, the Chrome windows are maximized.

Comment: Can you share a runnable example with a sample page? `monitor().catch(console.error)` is pointless since `monitor()` catches all errors that occur within it. I'd use loops and promises to retry instead of `setTimeout` with the old-style callback like this.